# Clock in Combined/Status Bar on ICS tablet overlaps the date when pops up

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, clock, notification-bar

The [Combined Bar](http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html#system-bars) (or Status Bar) on ICS shows the clock. When you tap this clock it pops up and shows details of any notifications. However, the clock in this popup overlaps the date on my DGM T-703 tablet when using 24-hour format.

I have tried altering the system font size, but it makes no difference to this part of the display.

NB: This is only an issue when using the 24-hour format, since the 12-hour format does not use a "0" prefix and the "1" (in 11:00 and 12:00) is such that it just about *wraps around* the date!

[image]

Is there any way to fix this untidiness and prevent an overlap?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this problem on any of ICS devices I have, most probably it pertains to the particular version installed on your tablet. Unless you want to modify the firmware yourself, the easiest fix would be to complain to the tablet maker and expect this to get fixed in the next release.

Comment: Yes, maybe so. My only puzzle is that, as far as I know, this is a very generic tablet with a very vanilla installation of Android.

Comment: vanilla installation of android leaves plenty of space to the left of time display, on my devices it's possible to write XXX hours (three decimal places) and there still be some space left. so I'm pretty sure your tablet maker customized framework-res.jar a lot.